# AndroidStudio aws django: HttpUrlConnection not working

Tags: android, android-studio, django-rest-framework, httprequest

I set up django on AWS account and trying to connect it to Android Studio using the following code. I can check that link is working in the browser but using Log.d I debugged that problem is in `urlConnection.connect()`.
Android Studio gives no error but any log after that is not printed.
I have also added permission in AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

I am a beginner please help me.

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {

        String site_url_json = "http://3.16.54.157:8002/post/";
        URL url = new URL(site_url_json);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        resultJson = buffer.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultJson;
}
```

Comment: The website you are trying to access is https://, but you are using HttpUrlConnection. Try using HttpsUrlConnection.

Comment: @Nolan I tried it but its not working with http also

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to implement this is to use this attribute to your `AndroidManifest.xml` where you allow all `http` for all requests:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

This gets ignored on older platforms. You will have to set this to true only in Android Pie and above.